# add android-support-v13.jar in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have been trying to add android-support-v13 in Android Studio 1.0.2

I have followed the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library) but I still get a build fail. Has anyone successfully managed to add android-support-v13.jar into Android Studio 1.0.2?

Below is my code in my gradle file.

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs',include: '*.jar')
```

Edit: I have installed extra support library from SDK manager and I have placed the .jar in my libs folder.

Comment: What error do you get? Also, have you installed the support repository through the Android SDK manager?

Comment: are you sure that `android-support-v13.jar` is inside your `libs` folder

Comment: Try this `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

according to [docs](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v13) at this time:

> The Gradle build script dependency identifier for this library is as
>   follows:
>
> `com.android.support:support-v13:18.0.0`

lets hope that the docs are updated.

for the latest you should use:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.+'
```

Comment: I fixed by compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.3'

Answer (score 2):

same problem android studio 1.0.2 i solve that below

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
```

Comment: how does this work? you cannot import same classes twice